# Guaranteed Winner in Multiple-Loss Elimination Bracket?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/208376/is-there-a-tally-of-the-number-of-12-win-arena-players) asks about the Hearthstone Arena.

The goal of the Hearthstone Arena is to reach 12 wins before losing 3 times. After 3 losses a contestant is eliminated. Hearthstone internally matches players against players of a matching record.

Gamepedia uses a "ball-bearing test" to find the possible outcomes: http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Arena#Statistics

There is a caveat mentioned [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/208376/is-there-a-tally-of-the-number-of-12-win-arena-players/208474#comment281999_208474) though: If Hearthstone *doesn't have* an 11-win player to match against another 11-win player it will take the next best thing, (say a 10-win player.) This clearly violates the parameters to the "ball-bearing test".

So my question is: Is a player still guaranteed to reach 12 wins if matches don't occur between contestants with an even number of wins?

Comment: The multiple-loss elimination is not particularly relevant, but rather that players that have been eliminated can re-enter the tournament.

Comment: @ken.ganong This question is actually more concerned with the idea that there could be a situation where 12 wins is perpetually unreachable because two 11-win contestants never play each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike the "ball-bearing test" Hearthstone has an "infinite" supply of players.

Since we know that for any given match there will always be one winner and one loser it is impossible to eliminate all contenders. In the worst case there will always be 1 player awaiting a match.

And for any given player who has not lost 3-matches, he has the potential to go on to win 12 matches.

So the *possibility* of a player winning 12 matches cannot be eliminated.

---

However, a situation can be contrived in which no player would exceed *x* wins, where *x*`> 3`.

Lets set *x*`= 4` for example. You have two players, *a* and *b*. Player *a* loses 2 matches to *b* then wins 3 matches against *b*. So *b* is eliminated and *a* has *x*`- 1` wins and 2 losses.

Given this setup we now begin a pattern:
Add 2 players have them play against each other till they both have 2 wins and 2 losses. Then have one of them play *a* and win, and play the other and lose. You now again have a player with 3 wins and 2 losses, who can now be *a*, and repeat the pattern.